# How can I find added lines (not changed) using git diff?

Tags: git

I've got a changelog text file in a project. I want to get list of changes from this file between 2 tags. I prepared this command:

```
git diff tag1..tag2 file | grep -v -e "+++ b/file" -e "@@" | grep "+"
```

As an output I receive all lines marked as added (beginning with `+`). But between them there might be some lines existed earlier, but modified between mentioned tags (for examplet corrected misspellings). Is there any option which allow to filter only new lines or only modified lines? Or maybe any option which allow to control the % condition of line's modification to be printed in output?

Comment: As I know, git marks changed lines as deleted old line and added new one. There is no "changed" line indicator. Although, you can see which deleted and added lines are on the same line number.

Comment: Sounds tricky. What do you want to happen for lines that were moved around in the file but not changed?

Comment: That lines would be in different place in the file, so I would treat them as new lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly I couldn't find any satisfying answer (nor here neither anywhere else), so I had to write necessary script myself.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not do this itself, and it's a hard problem in general, if you care about semantics rather than simple syntax.  Git does, however, come with a post-processing filter called `diff-highlight`.  The code inside this Perl script does the kind of syntax analysis you're interested in, so it could be modified to produce what you want.

See https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight for the source to diff-highlight.  Read through the README to see their notes about the semantic issues involved in this kind of analysis.  Note that [as of Git version 2.9](https://github.com/blog/2188-git-2-9-has-been-released), the highlight script is installed with the rest of Git, so that you do not have to fish it out of the contributed-sources area.